# Find the radius and the center of a Sphere.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I´m trying to understand how to find the radius and the center of a sphere. I have seen this video [radius of a sphere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WK6-MA05TPs.)

But for this case i have made some attemps and I found a different answer.

This is the equation $3x^2+3y^2+3z^2−8ly+4l^2=0$

I know that I can divide the whole equation by 3.

Comment: What answer did you find?  We cannot find any errors if we do not see your work.  Is $\l$ a parameter that your answer is supposed to depend on?

Comment: A sphere is not so far from a circle. Do you know how to deal with the equation of a circle?

Comment: The book answer is (2/3,0,0) and the center is 2/3.

Answer (score 1):

A general equation would be:

$$(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2 = r^2$$

for a sphere with radius $r$ centered at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$.

Putting your equation in this form gives

$$(x-0)^2 + (y-(4/3))^2 + (z - 0)^2 = (16/9) - 4l^2.$$

The center is at $(0,4/3,0)$ and we see that it's necessary that $|l| < 2/3$.

Comment: Sorry I dont know if I have made a mistake but there´s a l in the -8y.

Comment: Edit the equation in your question, and I'll edit my answer to reflect it.